# Ansible: Copying files from local to remote - "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'endswith'"

Tags: ansible

I am trying to copy files (scripts and rpms) stored locally to a set of servers. I can copy the files when the names are hard coded, but not when I am using a variable.

ansible-lint comes back with no errors.

When use variable replacement I get the error:

```
TASK [Copy cpu_gov.sh] 
***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'endswith'
fatal: [ceph3]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
```

In debug mode I can see that it is a Python error on a trailing "/". All other uses of the variable work fine, only when it is in the ""src:" field does it fail.

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 145, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 650, in _execute
    result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py", line 461, in run
    trailing_slash = source.endswith(os.path.sep)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'endswith'

fatal: [ceph3]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}
```

```
---
### Test
#

- hosts: all

  vars:
   #isdct_rpm: foobar.txt
   isdct_rpm: isdct-3.0.16-1.x86_64.rpm
   cpu_gov: cpu_gov.sh
   irq_bal: irq_balance.sh
   root_dir: /root
   bin_dir: /root/bin
   files_dir: /root/projects/ansible/bootstrap/files

  remote_user: root
  tasks:
```

These work just fine -

```
  - name: ISDCT rpm exists?
    stat:
      path: "{{ root_dir }}/{{ isdct_rpm }}"
    register: isdct_rpm
    tags:
       - tools

  - name: cpu_gov exists?
    stat:
      path: "{{ bin_dir }}/{{ cpu_gov }}"
    register: cpu_gov
    tags:
       - tools

  - name: irq_balance exists?
    stat:
      path: "{{ bin_dir }}/{{ irq_bal }}"
    register: irq_bal
    tags:
       - tools
```

The first task is the failing one:

```
  - name:  Copy ISDCT rpm
    copy:
      remote_src: no
      src: "{{ isdct_rpm }}"
      dest: "{{ root_dir }}"
    when: not isdct_rpm.stat.exists
```

These work fine:

```
  - name:  Copy rpm
    copy:
      remote_src: no
      src: isdct-3.0.16-1.x86_64.rpm
      dest: /root
    when: not isdct_rpm.stat.exists

  - name:  Copy cpu_gov.sh
    copy:
      remote_src: no
      src: cpu_gov.sh
      # - fails - src: "{{ cpu_gov }}"
      dest: "{{ bin_dir }}"
    when: not cpu_gov.stat.exists

  - name:  Copy irq_balance.sh
    copy:
      remote_src: no
      src: irq_balance.sh
      dest: /root
    when: not irq_bal.stat.exists
```

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 145, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 650, in _execute
    result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py", line 461, in run
    trailing_slash = source.endswith(os.path.sep)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'endswith'

fatal: [ceph3]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable in your `vars` section named `isdct_rpm` which is a string, but you're registering a dictionary variable with the same name in your `ISDCT rpm exists?` task.  This overrides the string value.

Stop trying to use the same variable name for two different purposes and I suspect things will work as expected.

Comment: Solved:  You can't use the same name for the register that you use for a variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@larsks Answered my question. I was using the same name for my variable and the register value. 
This works:

```
   #
  ###--- Copy the scripts over if needed
  #

  - name:  Copy ISDCT rpm
    copy:
      remote_src: no
      src: "{{ isdct_rpm }}"
      dest: "{{ root_dir }}"
    when: not isdctrpm.stat.exists

  - name:  Copy cpu_gov.sh
    copy:
      remote_src: no
      #src: cpu_gov.sh
      src: "{{ cpu_gov }}"
      dest: "{{ bin_dir }}"
    when: not cpugov.stat.exists

  - name:  Copy irq_balance.sh
    copy:
      remote_src: no
      src: "{{ irq_bal }}"
      dest: "{{ bin_dir }}"
    when: not irqbal.stat.exists
```